# Mouse shows color

Tags: java, windows, scripting, mouseover, windows-scripting

i am trying to make an application which would show which color my mouse is pointing to, i dont mean in my own application but anywhere in windows on any screen, kind of like a tag beside my mouse pointer which shows the exact color.

[image: example]

I am a Java developer but i dont think this could be done in java i am thinking maybe i need some sort of script but i have no idea any help would be really appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution consists of two parts:

**Part 1: Retrieving the color:**

```
Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
Color color = new Robot().getPixelColor(mouseLocation.x, mouseLocation.y);
```

**Part 2: Getting the color name:**

You can get a list of many colors and their names from [Wikipedia's List of colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors). You can create a mapping in Java given the data on Wikipedia.

Perhaps you can start with a few colors, and provide a generic hex representation for unknown colors, for example `#rrggbb`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the runnable example,

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class Main {

public static String getHexString(int rgb) {
    String hexString = Integer.toHexString(rgb);
    hexString = hexString.length() > 1 ? hexString : "0" + hexString;
    return hexString;
}

public static void main(String[] a) throws AWTException {
    Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    Color color = new Robot().getPixelColor(mouseLocation.x,
            mouseLocation.y);
    System.out.println(getHexString(color.getRed())
            + getHexString(color.getGreen())
            + getHexString(color.getBlue()));
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the code, i am trying to run a loop through this and printing the color but it is changing some times when i move the mouse but mostly it is staying the same, even when i am over a different color

Comment: you may sleep the thread instead of a loop, I guess it may be a timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel

There is a Java/AWT example, an AutoHotKey is a simple scripted option.

The second C example shows the 3 API calls you need `GetDC/GetCursorPos/GetPixel` and their support code, these can be used from most languages that compile for windows.